# Pulling website from git to production

Tags: git

I have a development server which I use for testing what I build on my local system. I made some changes and pushed them to GIT, merged with the "develop" branch then SSH into my develop server and pulled the develop branch in. I keep getting the following error:

error: Your local changes to 'app/Http/Controllers/CheckoutController.php' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting.
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.

I am not that good with Git, I know the basics and have been using it for a while now. I did a git status in the ssh and all of my changes from the last commits ( which I merged from my local branch to the develop branch within Git ) are listed as if they are not on the develop server ( showing modified, deleted, needs to be added ect. ).

Am I missing a step here? After I merge within GIT I should just be able to do a pull from SSH within the develop server website directory of this project and have it be there I figured.

One other thing, my business partner usually handles GIT. He has set up all projects and usually I just go through the normal motions. He is out of town so im on my own unless I want to wait, which im trying to avoid. So the original setup was in there and working until I started pushing code today.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If `develop` has the current state of the files that you want then you can `git checkout -- * && git pull` to get rid of any unwanted local changes and get a pristine version of what `develop` has

Comment: @CoryKramer are you saying to do this from the develop server? like through SSH command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git is telling you that `app/Http/Controllers/CheckoutController.php` has been edited since it was last pulled.  Pulling now would overwrite those changes, so git won't let you pull until you decide what to do with that file.

If you want to save the changes and commit them to the tree, `git commit` on the file and then `git push`.

If you want to temporarily save the changes and then decide later, run `git stash`.

If you want to discard the changes to that file, run a `git checkout` on the file.

Once you do one of these, you will be able to pull again.

Comment: Hi John, I just went in and tried to commit the files but its saying its already up to date. I decided to add a couple spaces into it just to see if this would work ( so it would appear as if changed were made ). I added, committed, pushed then merged within git. I then tried to pull and got the same error.

Comment: This doesn't seem to agree with your original post.  `git pull` said everything was up-to-date?  Was this on your local system or the development server?

Comment: John, I checked out the file as you suggested and was able to pull the code in. Thanks for the help. I need to definitely get stronger with GIT.